# How do I not simultaneously get all the color that I want in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have one div parent container and it contains five div child elements with some sort of names in it, and I have also div with an id named "arrow-up" and "arrow-down"(which is basically looked like this "<" ">" but pointing towards up and down ).

So basically the list of sorts name is on a column layout, then this two arrow is next to them. What I wanted is when I click any of this two arrow it'll color the specific list on name (like example if I click arrow-down it must colored the specific name ). But my problem is, it's simultaneously coloring all of the list name when I continue to click any of this two arrow. Is there a way to solve this?

```js
"use strict";
const getArrUp = document.getElementById("arrow-up");
const getArrDown = document.getElementById("arrow-down");

let dataFocus = 0;

getArrUp.addEventListener("click", function() {
  dataFocus++;
  let posY = ".data-info:nth-child(" + dataFocus + ")";
  document.querySelector(posY).style.color = "red";
});
```

```html
<!-- DATA CONTAINER -->
<div class="data-container">
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
</div>
<!-- ARROW CONTAINER -->
<div class="arrow-container">
  <div id="arrow-up" class="arrow-symb">↑</div>
  <div id="arrow-down" class="arrow-symb">↓</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only part in your code that changes the color to red, and there is no part that turns it back.

```js
const getArrUp = document.getElementById("arrow-up");
const getArrDown = document.getElementById("arrow-down");

let dataFocus = 0;

getArrUp.addEventListener("click", function() {
  dataFocus++;
  let posY = ".data-info:nth-child(" + dataFocus + ")";
  let dataInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".data-info");
  let dataInfoLen = dataInfo.length;
  for(let i = 0; i < dataInfoLen; i++) dataInfo[i].style.color = "unset";
  document.querySelector(posY).style.color = "red";
});
```

```html
<!-- DATA CONTAINER -->
<div class="data-container">
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
</div>
<!-- ARROW CONTAINER -->
<div class="arrow-container">
  <div id="arrow-up" class="arrow-symb">↑</div>
  <div id="arrow-down" class="arrow-symb">↓</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the state of the previous div, before change the color of the next div.

```js
const getArrUp = document.getElementById("arrow-up");
const getArrDown = document.getElementById("arrow-down");

let dataFocus = 0;

getArrUp.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('data-info')
  Array.from(divs).forEach(element => {
    element.style.color = ''
  })

  dataFocus++;
  let selector = ".data-info:nth-child(" + dataFocus + ")";
  let element = document.querySelector(selector)
  if(!element) {
    return
  }
  element.style.color = "red";
});
```

```html
<!-- DATA CONTAINER -->
<div class="data-container">
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
  <div class="data-info">Name of person</div>
</div>
<!-- ARROW CONTAINER -->
<div class="arrow-container">
  <div id="arrow-up" class="arrow-symb">↑</div>
  <div id="arrow-down" class="arrow-symb">↓</div>
</div>
```